# Translate points on GestureDetector superimposed on a map to coordinates on the map (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, mapbox-gl

How do I compute the geo-coordinate of a point, on click/pan (captured using a GestureDetector), that superimposes a map, assuming I already know the bounds of the map (southwest and northeast coordinates).

Say, these are the map bounds:

```
LatLngBounds(
  LatLng(
    -33.95417947321306, 151.13752893137473
  ),
  LatLng(
    -33.712914147376225, 151.28447106862006
  )
)
```

And, my GestureDetector captures this offset `onPanStart`: `Offset(181.3, 283.7)`
How do I calculate the coordinate the offset refers to, on the map?
I’m using the `mapbox_gl` flutter plugin and, it doesn’t support `pan` events in itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit more search but, I found a method of the `MapboxMapController` that supports this sort of coordinate-conversion from a point on the screen, to the corresponding coordinate on the map behind it.

The method is `MapboxMapController.toLatLng(Point screenLocation)`.